# distancebetween sql function and order by closest

Tags: sql, sql-server, nerddinner

Im using this function to get events within 30 miles, its pretty much the same as the nerd dinner one. But How can I order them by 'closest'..?

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[NearestEvents] 
  ( 
  @lat real, 
  @long real 
  ) 
RETURNS  TABLE 
AS 
  RETURN 
  SELECT Events.ID 
  FROM   Events  
  WHERE  dbo.DistanceBetween(@lat, @long, Latitude, Longitude) <30
```

Comment: If you want the same results but ordered by closet, you'll probably need to store the data into a temp table that includes the column DistanceBetween and then select the results ordered on the DistanceBetween column.  It's some extra work, because the distance between is calculated on the fly.

Answer (score 3):

Add it to your SELECT list.

```
SELECT Events.ID,
  dbo.DistanceBetween(@lat, @long, Latitude, Longitude) as distance
  FROM   Events  
  WHERE  dbo.DistanceBetween(@lat, @long, Latitude, Longitude) <30 
  ORDER BY distance
```

--Since it is still not working for OP a good way to debug stored procedure is by hijacking the parameters.  Try this with your Query Analyser and see that you get:

```
DECLARE @lat = varchar(100);
DECLARE @long = vavhar(100);

SET @lat = 'XXXXX';
SET @long = 'XXXXX';

 SELECT Events.ID,
      dbo.DistanceBetween(@lat, @long, Latitude, Longitude) as distance
      FROM   Events  
      WHERE  dbo.DistanceBetween(@lat, @long, Latitude, Longitude) <30 
      ORDER BY distance;
```

Comment: query missing comma, should be: 'Events.ID, dbo.DistanceBetween(...'

Comment: I tried that, it still doesnt work, im getting : The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.